# child clickable/parent longclickable

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I have a `FrameLayout` with `TextView` in it.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:autoLink="email|web|phone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

My `TextView` has autoLink enabled for email/web/phone, as you can see. But my `FrameLayout` has `LongClickListener` in code.

```
flContainer.setOnLongClickListener { 
        // some work
    }
```

But when I try to longtap to parent FL though the child TextView, it doesn't work, because TV intercepts click and doesn't allow parent to get longclick. 
I know the simple solution - just apply the same longClickListener to TextView, but I have `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on my FL, so it should have ripple effect when I click it, but TV consumes it. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Try using android:addStatesFromChildren="true" and tell me if it works.

Comment: @VedprakashWagh exactly what I need! Can you post an answer for my question? I will approve it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I'll add more information about it in a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:addStatesFromChildren="true"` in your parent layout. As mentioned in the documentation,

> Sets whether this ViewGroup's drawable states also include its
>   children's drawable states. This is used, for example, to make a group
>   appear to be focused when its child EditText or button is focused.

You can find about it here:

[android.view.ViewGroup](http://%20https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#attr_android:addStatesFromChildren)